# jquery select element with multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, forms, css-selectors

Ok..i'm having a brainfart right now with jquery's selector process (yes, it's quite confusing to start).

I have 2 input elements on the page, of which I want to remove one.

here are my inputs:

`<input value="blahblah@blah.com" name="Email" type="hidden">`

`<input value="blahblah@blah.com" id="Email" name="Email" type="text">`

I have a blur method on #Email that will remove the hidden Email field.  Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time targeting it to remove it.

Can someone help relieve my brainfart?  I tried using :not, multiple attributes, etc.  The hidden field is server generated and I can't stop it from being sent back.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('input[type=hidden][name=Email]').remove();
```

should do. You can learn more about jQuery selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[name=Email][type=hidden]').remove()
```

Comment: freakin' awesome!  thank you keith and balusC!  I'm getting better with jQuery everyday with the help of the SO community!