# How to identify an element with multiple matched attributes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="something" data-id="1" data-count="5">Some text here</div>

<div class="something" data-id="2" data-count="14">Some text here</div>
```

Now how can I add a specific class say 'addthisclass' using jQuery to the `<div>` whose 'data-id' is equal to 1 and 'data-count' is equal to 5?

**Edit**

'*something*' is the class. By mistake I typed it as id.

Comment: How can I do this without reference to the ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select elements on multiple attribute values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045071/how-do-i-select-elements-on-multiple-attribute-values) and [jQuery match multiple attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155977/jquery-match-multiple-attributes) and [jquery select element with multiple attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2292067/218196).

Comment: What have you tried so far btw? jQuery has an extensive selectors documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple attribute selectors:

```
$("div[data-id=1][data-count=5]").addClass("addthisclass");
```

If desired, you can combine those with a class selector as well:

```
$("div.something[data-id=1][data-count=5]").addClass("addthisclass");
```

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder. Still need to develop my jQuery knowledge :)

Comment: @SuryaS: You're welcome! In this case, it's CSS knowledge (the bit in quotes is a [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and can also include some [jQuery-specific pseudo-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).