# JQuery multiple attributes with logic AND?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use multiple attribute selectors but I need them to work as if it had AND logic.  The object needs to have both attributes being asked.  Currently I have this.

```
$("#EquipmentTable[data-table='#Overview1'][data-key='plat1']")
```

But It doesn't seem to be taking it in that it must have both data objects to find or use the record.  Can anyone verify if this is the correct way to go about this or if there is a better way.

Thanks,

Comment: What you have there should work fine. Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net example of the problem? The only way I could see this not working is if you added one or both of the `data` attributes via `$.data()`. That way they would be in jQuery's cache and not directly available on the DOMElement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292067/jquery-select-element-with-multiple-attributes

Comment: The content of the web page is sensitive as it's for a client.  But the data was added direct in the html tags so it wasn't added with the $.data() 

<table data-KEY="#plat1" data-TABLE="#Overview1" id="EquipmentTable"></table>

Comment: Sorry I typed that wrong when I re-typed it. should read 

<table data-KEY="plat1" data-TABLE="#Overview1" id="EquipmentTable"></table>

Comment: In that case, unable to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/3ph406m0/ That works fine.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help trying to trouble shoot a logical error is tricky. So I wanted to make sure that I was correct before I tried something else.

Answer (score -1):

for multiple attribute values you can use filter or find methods of jquery.

like

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').filter('[name="abc"]').filter('[required="required"]').filter('[readonly="readonly"]').css("background","red");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  readonly="readonly" required="required"/>
<input type="text"  readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="text"  readonly="readonly" required="required" name="abc"/>
```

for reference

[A cleaner way to select by multiple possible attribute values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471775/a-cleaner-way-to-select-by-multiple-possible-attribute-values)